# jQuery keyUp function triggered more than once even though the event happened only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
   $( "#zip" ).focus(function() {
       $( "#zip" ).keyup(function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode == '38' || event.keyCode == '40'){
              $('#city').addClass('loadinggif');
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to add the `loadinggif` class to the `city` input only when user has `form select` in focus and when he presses arrow up or down.

However I am experiencing that the event is happening more than once even if I press the key only once.

Any idea?

Comment: The `$("#zip").keyup` code will only fire when a key is pressed when `#zip` has focus, so there's no need to "check" for focus first.

Comment: Yea I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding `keyup` event inside `focus` event handler thus multiple event handler's are binded for `keyup` event.

Move `keyup` event binding outside `focus` event handler.

```
$( "#zip" ).focus(function() {       
});
$( "#zip" ).keyup(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == '38' || event.keyCode == '40'){
          $('#city').addClass('loadinggif');
      }
});
```

Comment: Makes sense... thank you :) So I don't need focus at all, right?